# Multiple line node labels in Decision Tree diagram

Tags: diagrams, pst-tree

I've been struggling with this and am hoping someone will be able to help me. I'm trying to recreate the following diagram (picture attached) using the pstree package. However it doesn't seem to let me break the node labels into multiple lines as in the original picture, using \. If someone could please assist that'd help me a great deal.

My code so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-tree}
\psset{treemode=D,nodesep=7pt}

\begin{document}
\psTree{\Tr{[± conceptually activated] // Content morphemes and early system morphemes}}
    \psTree{\Tr{[+conceptually activated]}}
        \Tr{[+thematic role]}
        \Tr{[-thematic role]}
    \endpsTree
    \psTree{\Tr{[-conceptually activated]}}
        \Tr{-refer to grammatical information outside of Maximal Projection of Head}
        \Tr{+refer to grammatical information outside of Maximal Projection of Head}
    \endpsTree
\endpsTree

\end{document}
```

Thank you,

[image]

Comment: Could you add the code and output of what you've tried so far?

Comment: I have added the code I've got so far. As you can see the \\ didn't work for the line break, so I've stopped short there.

Comment: I get an error when I want to compile your code. However, have you tried to put the text inside a `\parbox`?

Comment: I'm not sure what the compiling error is, it works for me (except because the line break doesn't work, it stretched outside the margin of the page). I'm quite amateur at LaTeX, so if you can elaborate on how \parbox works that'll help.

Comment: I get the error `Undefined control sequence. \psTree{\Tr{[+conceptually activated]}}`